# Translation direction in separating axis theorem

Tags: collision-detection

I have implementen the separating axis theorem in java.
The collision detection itself works great. 
But i am stuck when it comes to resolve the collision.

my method to get the translation looks like this:

```
public float getOverlap(final Projection other) {
    float start = m_min > other.m_min ? m_min : other.m_min;
    float end = m_max < other.m_max ? m_max : other.m_max;
    float translation = end - start;
    return translation;
}
```

Lets say the projection of the two rectangles in the picture looks like this.

```
R1.min = 2
R1.max = 8
R2.min = 5
R2.max = 11
```

[image: Separating axis translation]

When i check R1 vs. R2 the translation will be 3
When i checl R2 vs. R1 the translation also will be 3

now i add the translation to the normalized axis

```
Normalized axis = Vector(1,0)
Translation Vector = Vector(1,0)*3 = Vector (3,0)
```

And now R1 and R2 both move 3 points to the right, but they are suposed to move in different directions. R1 should move Vector(-3,0), R2 should move Vector(3,0).

how can i compute the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution:

I substract the center vector R1 from center Vector R2, build the dot product to the tested axis and invert the translation if the dotproduct is smaller then 0

```
Vector centerR1(R1.x,R1.y);
Vector centerR2(R2.x,R2.y);

Vector R1toR2 = centerR2 - centerR1;

if(R1toR2.dot(axis)<0){
  translation = -translation
}
```

"When the vector (R1toR2) points in an negative direction, invert the translation"

Answer (score 0):

Just gonna post another answer here that solved it for me.

The solution with the dot product didn't work for me, although you seem to check if the dot is `< 0` in your answer whereas everywhere else I've seen the check to be `>= 0`, so I'm not sure would that change anything.

I decided that I would return either a positive or negative overlap in my `getOverlap` function, and this would indicate the direction of resolution. This would depend on whether the first object's min is less than the second object's min or not.

```
// Check for overlap of two 1 dimensional lines
function getLineOverlap(min1, max1, min2, max2) {
    let min = Math.max(min1, min2);
    let max = Math.min(max1, max2);

    // if negative, no overlap
    let result = Math.max(max - min, 0);

    // add positive/negative sign depending on direction of overlap
    return result * ((min1 < min2) ? 1 : -1);
};
```

If this still doesn't work, you might need to multiply your resulting resolution vector by `-1`.

I got this solution from [this stackoverflow answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/27633/126355).